# VB.Net - execute vbscript using process with 'run as administrator'

Tags: vb.net, process, vbscript

I have a vbscript file that I want to run in my vb.net application.  In the application, the script 'must' use a process.  The reason is that it's actually being called from a windows process.  In order for me to execute the vbscript manually, I have to right-click on the shortcut and select 'run as administrator'.

How can I emulate this using vb.net?  Currently the execution works because I tested it with it only creating a text file.  Also, I want to assume that the user is in the administrators group and don't want them to have to login each time because it will execute every minute.

My code:

```
Dim foo As New System.Diagnostics.Process
foo.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "c:\"
foo.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
foo.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
foo.StartInfo.Arguments = "%comspec% /C cscript.exe //B //Nologo C:\aaa\test.vbs"
foo.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
foo.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
foo.Start()
foo.WaitForExit()
foo.Dispose()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, twice I've tried using the 'code' function.  It displays correcly in the preview pane but not when I post it!!??

Comment: Put a line break/carriage return between "My code:" and "Dim..." to get the code to display correctly. I'd do it myself but its too minor an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class ProcessStartInfo has two properties that can be used to define the user name that will run your script

[ProcessStartInfo.UserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.username.aspx)
[ProcessStartInfo.Password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.password)

Please note as from MSDN:
`The WorkingDirectory property must be set if UserName and Password are provided. If the property is not set, the default working directory is %SYSTEMROOT%\system32.`

The Password property is of type SecureString. This class need a special initialization code like this:

```
  ' Of course doing this will render the secure string totally 'insecure'
  Dim pass As String = "Password"
  Dim passString As SecureString = New SecureString()
  For Each c As Char In pass
     passString.AppendChar(ch)
  Next
```

So your code could be changed in this way

```
Dim foo As New System.Diagnostics.Process   
foo.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "c:\"   
foo.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True   
foo.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"   
foo.StartInfo.Arguments = "%comspec% /C cscript.exe //B //Nologo C:\aaa\test.vbs"   
foo.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False   
foo.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True   
foo.StartInfo.UserName = "administrator"
foo.StartInfo.Password = passString
foo.Start()   
foo.WaitForExit()   
foo.Dispose()
```

Comment: Hi mate.  Cheers for getting back.  I did look but didn't think it would achieve what I needed (sorry, I should have stated) and here's why...  What happens if the user changes their password?  I don't want to have to specify a username or password.  Much like when I run now manually.  I can just right click and select 'run as adminstrator' where I'm not prompted for any credentials.  Is that possible?

Comment: No, I think that is not possible. If you want to run something as another user, you need to sign in with user and password. However, if the changing of password is your problem, then ask it to the user, just at the start of your program, and keep it in memory (as a SecureString) for the lifetime of the program launching the vb.script.