# unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException'

Tags: windows, vb.net, exception, vbscript

First time poster long time reader. I want to say thank you guys for all of your work. I have been working on a VB project, currently we have some tools written in dos however its dated and currently just doesn't work for &%^$. What I have in batch is this.

```
if exist %userprofile%\Local GOTO W7

RD  /s /q "%userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Our Company Folder"

RD  /s /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Our Company Folder"
```

What this does is delete our company config folder when corruption has occurred.

Since we have a support tool created in VB I want to change this command to VB.

This is what I have now is

```
     Dim fso
        Dim wshshell As Object
        Dim USRPROFILE
        fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        wshshell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
        USRPROFILE = wshshell.expandenvironmentstrings("%APPDATA%")
        If fso.FolderExists(USRPROFILE & "\Our Company Folder") Then
            fso.DeleteFolder(USRPROFILE & "\Our Company Folder")
        End If
        USRPROFILE = wshshell.expandenvironmentstrings("%HOMEPATH%")
        If fso.FolderExists(USRPROFILE & "\Local Settings\Application Data\Our Company Folder") Then
            fso.DeleteFolder(USRPROFILE & "\Local Settings\Application Data\Our Company Folder")
      End If
End Sub
```

However I am getting this error message. 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0046 (CTL_E_PERMISSIONDENIED)

Answer (score 0):

What I would read that message as is that the user running the VB code doesn't have permission to delete the folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is that whomever you are executing the program as doesn't have correct permissions, so you have a couple of options.

- Change the folder permissions
- Log on as someone with permissions
- Or run the process as someone else as suggested in the link below:

[VB.Net - execute vbscript using process with 'run as administrator'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233788/vb-net-execute-vbscript-using-process-with-run-as-administrator)